# Node.js не принимает данные из FormData()

Tags: node.js, post, formdata

Данные из браузера отправляются таким образом:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("test", "123");

var res = new XMLHttpRequest();
res.open( "post", "/post", true );
res.send(formData);
```

Приходят в Node.js (express)

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post("/post", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(null);
});
```

И там пустой объект {}
Если отправить данные из обычной формы, то все нормально.
Если отправить http post запрос из какого-нибудь ангуляра, тоже все нормально.
Из FormData() не приходит как будто ничего.

Я уже много чего пробовал.
К примеру если отправить с таким хэдером

```js
res.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

То в итоге что-то приходит. Там даже есть нужные данные. Непонятно только как их раскодировать

```
{ '------WebKitFormBoundaryhACdDHCWbVp8Xjtp\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"test"\r\n\r\n123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryhACdDHCWbVp8Xjtp--\r\n' }
```

Очень странно. В интернете почему-то нет никого с такой же проблемой.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение.

```
var multer = require("multer");

//...

var upload = multer({ dest: "./upload/" });
app.post("/post", upload.array(), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(null);
}
```

Теперь все работает всегда.
Бонусом можно заливать файлы. Подробности по обработке файлов можете почитать в доках по multer...

Comment: с `multer` работает? у меня тоже `WebKitFormBoundaryh...` возвращается